# How I can test if numbers are in a specific range?

Tags: java, range

How I can check if a number is with-in a specific range?

I wanted to find an number between 0 and 500, so I tried

```
int k = 200;
if (k <= 0 && k > 500)
    if (k <= 0 && k > 249)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand the question or your code. if k is between 0 and 500, then k >= 0 && k <= 500 inclusive.

Comment: What number is both less than or equal to `0` ***and*** greater than `500` *at the same time*? You almost certainly want `k <= 500` **not** `k > 500` (so you could also use `!(k > 500)`).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch **TO INFINITY AND BEYOND!**

Comment: @codeCompiler77 I guess it's more [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane) than it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easiest if you plot your logic on a numberline:

`if (k...0 and 501...k) //= false`
`if (k...0 and 250...k) //= false`

The problem is that you are checking if k is outside the range right now. Try changing your logic to `k >= min and k <= max`

Answer (score 0):

Check the range (0 to 500) like below :

**Inclusive**

```
if (k>= 0 && k<= 500) {
     //....
}
```

**Exclusive**

```
 if (k> 0 && k < 500) {
  //....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a number is in [0,500]:

```
if(number >= 0 && number <= 500) {
    // is number in [0,250]?
    if(number <= 250) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

If you want to check if a number is in (0,500):

```
if(number > 0 && number < 500) {
    // is number in (0,250)?
    if(number < 250) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Does this help you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(k >= 0 && k <= 500) {
    // do something
}
```

The above code will check whether the value of '`k`' is `0 or more than 0` and `500 or less than 500`.

```
if(k > 0 && k < 500) {
        // do something
}
```

The above code will check whether the value of '`k`' is in `between 0 and 500`.